Count Consecutive Months in SQL
I am not getting the output I want with my current SQL code. I added “row number” and "WHAT I WANT" for ease. Row 4 is not working properly. This is happening throughout the code when I don’t specify the ID as well. I am specifying this ID for the sake of understanding what is going on in the code. For row 4, it should be “2” for Consecutive, not 1 because the row above it is 1 month before. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?
My end goal (which i have not coded for yet) is to look at which IDs have at least 12 consecutive months.
SELECT year, ID, YearMo
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, gap ORDER BY yearmo) AS Consecutive
FROM (
SELECT year, ID, YearMo
        ,CASE WHEN yearmo - LAG(yearmo, 1, yearmo - 1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY yearmo) IN (1, 89) 
            THEN 0 ELSE 1 
        END 
+ 
SUM(CASE WHEN yearmo - LAG(yearmo, 1, yearmo - 1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY yearmo) IN (1, 89) 
         THEN 0 ELSE 1 
    END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY yearmo) as gap
    FROM T1
) subquery
where ID = "7"
ORDER BY 
    ID, 
    yearmo




Row #
year
ID
YearMo
Consecutive
WHAT I WANT




1
2019
7
201901
1
1


2
2019
7
201902
2
2


3
2019
7
201905
1
1


4
2019
7
201906
1
2


5
2019
7
201908
1
1


6
2019
7
201910
1
1


7
2019
7
201911
2
2


8
2019
7
201912
3
3


9
2020
7
202001
4
4


10
2020
7
202002
5
5


11
2020
7
202003
6
6


12
2020
7
202006
1
1


13
2020
7
202007
2
2


14
2020
7
202008
3
3


15
2020
7
202009
4
4


16
2020
7
202010
5
5


17
2020
7
202011
6
6


18
2020
7
202012
7
7




Most of the time in SQL if you're thinking "consecutive", you should think "Gaps and islands", and that will lead you to the solution. (Occasionally you might just do Lag/Lead).

@JoelCoehoorn Would you be able to fix the code I did to make it correct? I have tried many different iterations and have struggled to get to the solution.

As @JoelCoehoorn said, this is a "gaps and islands" question.
You didn't say which RDBMS you are using and provided only one ID.  My solution works in SQL Server with the limited inputs you provided.  Your mileage may vary.
;
with
T1 (
    [Row]
  , [year]
  , [ID]
  , [YearMo]
  , [WHAT I WANT]
) as (
  select *
  from (
    values
      (1, 2019, 7, 201901, 1)
    , (2, 2019, 7, 201902, 2)
    , (3, 2019, 7, 201905, 1)
    , (4, 2019, 7, 201906, 2)
    , (5, 2019, 7, 201908, 1)
    , (6, 2019, 7, 201910, 1)
    , (7, 2019, 7, 201911, 2)
    , (8, 2019, 7, 201912, 3)
    , (9, 2020, 7, 202001, 4)
    , (10, 2020, 7, 202002, 5)
    , (11, 2020, 7, 202003, 6)
    , (12, 2020, 7, 202006, 1)
    , (13, 2020, 7, 202007, 2)
    , (14, 2020, 7, 202008, 3)
    , (15, 2020, 7, 202009, 4)
    , (16, 2020, 7, 202010, 5)
    , (17, 2020, 7, 202011, 6)
    , (18, 2020, 7, 202012, 7)
  ) q ([Row]
    , [year]
    , [ID]
    , [YearMo]
    , [WHAT I WANT])
),
Groups as (
  SELECT 
    [Row]
  , [year]
  , [ID]
  , [YearMo]
  , [WHAT I WANT]
  , CASE 
      WHEN yearmo - LAG(yearmo, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY yearmo) IN (1, 89) 
        THEN 0
      ELSE 1 
    END  AS IslandStartInd
  FROM T1
),
Islands as (
  SELECT 
    [Row]
  , [year]
  , [ID]
  , [YearMo]
  , [WHAT I WANT]
  , IslandStartInd
  , SUM(IslandStartInd) OVER (ORDER BY ID, YearMo) AS IslandId
  FROM Groups
)

SELECT 
  [Row]
, [year]
, [ID]
, [YearMo]
, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ID, IslandId order by YearMo) as Consecutive
, [WHAT I WANT]
FROM Islands
ORDER BY ID, YearMo;

